# Windows Firewall Rule doesn't work - Firewall API - C#

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-10, windows-firewall-api

i programmed a small chat program which is coded in C#. It uses WCF, to communicate with other users in the local network. Furthermore it uses the Firewall API dll in System32 to add 4 rules which allows all ports for incoming/outgoing TCP and UDP connections for this program. This rules are adding themselfe in the current network configuration(Public, Private). When the program Is closing, it deletes the 4 rules.
The problem is, that the firewall ignores this rules and drops  the data which Is incomming. When i deactivate the firewall on both pcs(the two which are communicating) it works without problems.
The firewall has this 4 rules activated but i don't really get it why the firewall drops the incoming data...

Tested on 4 different Windows 10 machines.
After I think 1,5 hours the firewall rules worked on one machine which Is also confusing me...

This is the method with that i create this rules:

```
    private void FWRule(NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_ direction,
    NET_FW_ACTION_ fwaction, NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_ protocol, bool add)
    {
        try
        {
            INetFwRule firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
            INetFwMgr fwMgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWMgr"));

            firewallRule.Action = fwaction;
            firewallRule.Enabled = true;
            firewallRule.InterfaceTypes = "All";
            firewallRule.serviceName ="Chatty";
            firewallRule.Grouping = "Chatty";

            firewallRule.Profiles = (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE_.NET_FW_PROFILE_CURRENT;
            firewallRule.ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            if (protocol == NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP)
                firewallRule.Name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + " Server Remote TCP";
            else if (protocol == NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP)
                firewallRule.Name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + " Server Remote UDP";

            firewallRule.Protocol = (int)protocol;
            INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance
            (Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
            firewallRule.Direction = direction;

            if (add == true)
            {
                firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);
            }
            else
            {
                firewallPolicy.Rules.Remove(firewallRule.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR"); }
    }
```

The log from the firewall of the Server program shows that the firewall drops the incoming TCP data from the client(the server port for TCP is 2310, the client port for TCP is random/not known):

```
2016-10-19 10:37:56 DROP ICMP :: ff02::1 - - 80 - - - - 130 0 - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:38:54 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50248 2310 72 S 1175516710 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:38:57 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50248 2310 72 S 1175516710 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:39:03 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50248 2310 68 S 1175516710 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:40:02 DROP ICMP :: ff02::1 - - 80 - - - - 130 0 - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:02 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50252 2310 72 S 4091559822 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:05 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50252 2310 72 S 4091559822 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:11 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50252 2310 68 S 4091559822 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:23 DROP TCP 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.121 50253 2310 52 S 3013060805 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:26 DROP TCP 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.121 50253 2310 52 S 3013060805 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:30 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50261 2310 72 S 1985828196 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:33 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50261 2310 72 S 1985828196 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:41:39 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50261 2310 68 S 1985828196 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:42:07 DROP ICMP :: ff02::1 - - 80 - - - - 130 0 - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:44:13 DROP ICMP :: ff02::1 - - 80 - - - - 130 0 - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:44:28 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50285 2310 72 S 2762432965 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:44:29 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50285 2310 72 S 2762432965 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
2016-10-19 10:44:35 DROP TCP fe80::91c:1ba7:abfc:5e5f fe80::1c96:dc05:3b26:1eaa 50285 2310 68 S 2762432965 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
```

The rule is registered in the Windows Firewall(sorry OS is in German):

[image]

Comment: We really can't say anything about this. Your assumption _"the firewall ignores this rules and drops the data which Is incoming"_ may be incorrect. Are the machines that don't work behind NAT, and the one that does work on a direct (albeit switched) network connection?

Comment: It seems like a bad idea for microsoft to allow any random piece of software to be able to delete and re-add firewall rules at will. What if it was MalWare? Where is the code that does this?

Comment: @Liam you need to be administrator for those calls to work. See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/securitytools/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c/

Comment: so is this running as Admin?

Comment: @Liam if not, this approach wouldn't work and throw exceptions, and since the OP doesn't mention any exceptions I guess they want to develop a chat application that requires administrative privileges.

Comment: The program has the Admin rights implemented in the Manifest file.

Comment: I read the log file from the firewall, the firewall dropped this incoming packages...

Comment: The 2 machines(normal PCs) are connected to a simple router. With UDP on Port 80 the Client program finds the server(Windows Discovery), but When it tries to connect with the Server it throws TimeOutExeption because the Server Never got this Message and couldn't answere.

Comment: Please show the relevant code so we can better help with the issue.

Comment: @JimmySmith I added the method which creates/removes the rules to the firewall. 
Do you need something else too?

Comment: @Tormod you manage to solve it ? the problem is that windows enforce rules that under "monitoring" section (Uberwcheng) in firwall table which are not add there with the api